# What is the lightest HTML color code for readable cross platform web pages?

Tags: cross-platform, user-experience

I want my slightly faded text to be readable in both Mac, Windows, iOS, and Android.

Assuming a white background, what is the lightest shade of gray that would still be safely readable for the average viewer considering indoor lighting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found HTML color codes around `#777` to be faded yet still readable for my purposes.

This may not be ideal for certain visually-impaired readers, laptops with small viewing angles, or screens susceptible to glare.

Answer (score -1):

You can try use #95a5a6 for your text..